# MathJAX in Android

Tags: android, webview, mathjax

I am trying to display math formulae in Android's webview. I ve written the code in a separate html file and using the following code to display the formulae:

```
String data =inputStreamToString1();
myWebView.loadData(data, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

I've placed the following lines in the html file to load mathJAX dynamically:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
   src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
</script>
```

The problem is when I run the app in emulator(Android version 2.2) mathJAX is not loading up. However in my phone (Android version 2.1), mathJAX loads correctly.

Can anyone tell me the reason for this problem?

Also when the webview opens in the emulator, I get the following warning:

"webcore    Not supported in this case"

Does this warning have anything to do with not loading mathJAX?

Comment: First you can try local copy of MathJax. Second, try different configurations.

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips (and perhaps update your post for future readers).