# Android - Display formulas in multiple choice questions

Tags: android, math, webview, android-webview, formula

I'm working on creating a small android app to display multiple choice questions. Few of the question/answer choices has complex mathematical formulas. I'm able to display formulas using WebView + JavaScript for the question part but not sure what's the best way to implement this in the multiple choices answers.

How do I implement this?

Comment: Maybe [mathjax](http://www.mathjax.org/) would do this for you, as used on [math](http://math.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a set of radio buttons with formulas next to them rendered using [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/). Unless you encounter errors running [MathJAX in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6492152/1468366), that is.

As an alternative, you could create the MathML by [some other means](http://www.w3.org/Math/Software/), perhaps while authoring the questions, and then embed that into the HTML next to the radio buttons.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, we did implement using radio button and it displays fine but having trouble with alignment. We are using jqmath to display formulas. Thanks for the suggestion.